# How can I add response header in MAUI Blazor app?

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

ASP.NET Blazor Server app has possibility to add response headers like described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-7.0

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "{POLICY STRING}");
    await next();
});
```

But I am missing that functionality in MAUI Blazor app.

[image: MauiApp]

I need to add something like that:

```
if (ctx.File.Name.EndsWith(".br")) {
    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "br");
}
```

There is possibility to add response header in Apache server side, but I am looking way how to handle it in code like in ASP.NET Blazor Server app... Any ideas?

Comment: [As you probably know] An *"http response"* is made by a **server** to a client. Its something that runs on a web *server*, not on a web *client*. `Maui blazor` runs in an app, thus is usually intended to be a web *client*, not a web server (AFAIK). Please explain in more detail how you are using this app, such that you need server functionality. Bottom line: IANAE (I am not an expert), but I think you will have to do it in whatever web server code you are running on the device, and have the app communicate with that server.

Comment: Just like ToolmakerSteve said, the `app` in the `app.Use` is the instance of the `WebApplication` in the Blazor's server part's program.cs. in the AspNetCore Blazor. But for the maui blazor, it doesn't have the web server part.